# requestLocationUpdates MinDistance Unit

Tags: java, android, android-gps

I want get an update of the user's location everytime he changes his location. I have used requestLocationUpdates in which min distance is there. But my doubt is what is the distance unit for this?

If I want to update when user moves 2 Km what number should I give in min distance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean [LocationManager's requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)), the Javadoc says:

> `minDistance`, float: minimum distance between location updates, **in meters**

So 2Km would be 2000.